# How do I set the file version and product version properties for a self-extracting zip file?

Tags: file, attributes, zip, version, self-extracting

I have an EXE file which is a self-extracting zip file. How do I set the product version and file version on the EXE file? Windows lists them in the file properties, but they are all blank. The Description field available in Winzip seems to have no impact on file properties.

I am using Winzip Self-Extractor 4.0 Personal Edition, but other solutions/workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resource editor to manually change the product and file versions of an executable. There are many available on the internet such as [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/), [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are programmatically producing this self-extracting zip, you can use DotNetZip to do it. There's a programmatic interface to specify all that stuff.